# Save a fetchedObject NSArray to NSUserDefaults - app crashes at launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, widget, nsuserdefaults

I am doing a today extension widget for an existing app. The app saves to `Core Data` an image.

This is the fetch request:

```
- (NSArray *)pictures {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Images"];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[Stack sharedInstance].managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    [self saveToWidget]; // Method to save NSArray pictures to NSUserDefaults.

    return fetchedObjects;
}
```

This is the method that will save the NSArray to the NSUserDefaults:

```
- (void)saveToWidget {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"group.AppJester.PicPocket"];

    //save the MutableArray to NSUserdefaults
    [userDefaults setObject:self.pictures forKey:@"image"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

**Important Fact**

Every time the user takes a picture and save it to the app, it's automatically saved to core data, and in order to be shown at the main screen (UICollectionView) I pull all pictures from the **pictures** array.

**The NSUserDefaults are supposed to save the images to an Array to be retrieved at the Widget Target and displayed that the Today Extension.**

If I add the `[self saveToWidget]` method to the fetchRequest the app crashes. I am assuming that's the problem because if I remove it, it works fine.

Comment: Another **Important Fact** might be the actual console output from the crash and what line it's crashing on...

Comment: @nhgrif the app doesn't act on the crash. The simulator is crashed and Xcode does not log anything. I even waited for a while to see if anything changes and NOTHING

Comment: Reset the simulator's content & settings and try again?

Comment: @nhgrif I have done all that and even restart Xcode, computer etc...  What I am looking here is a suggestion on how to save the fetchRequest Array to the NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The PROBLEM**

Xcode was not reaction because the entire computer would freeze after I ran the app.

**Fixing the NSArray**

My fetch request was bringing a custom object, and NSUserDefaults does not support custom objects. So I am converting the NSArray to a NSData.